# Storing the results of InStr() into an array for use with a VBS loop

Tags: arrays, loops, vbscript

I am fairly new to vbscript and programming in general(less than a year). I am writing an ASP classic page that returns results from a database. One field in the database returns an unformatted string of text. I need to search the text for numbers with a period next to them. For each of those found I want to start a new line for example:

```
    comments = "New String 1.blah 2.blah 3.blah 4.blah 5.blah 6.blah"
```

While playing with the idea and researching stack and other sites I came up with the following:

1. Trim the blank space on the left w/ Trim() and search the string for a number followed by a period.
       n1 = Trim(InStr(comments, 1&".")) -1
       n2 = Trim(InStr(comments, 2&".")) -1
2. Determine the number of characters between the numbered positions by subtracting the previous number:

   ```
   p1 = n1-n0
   p2 = n2-n1
   p3 = n3-n1
   ```
3. Print the results using vbs Left() and Mid()

   ```
   response.write(Left(comments,n1) & "</br>")
   response.write(Mid(comments,n1,p2) &"</br")
   response.write(Mid(commesnt,n2,p3) &"</br>")
   ```
4. Returns the result

New String

1.blah

2.blah

3.blah

etc.
and so forth

Where my difficulties are arising is when I am trying to store everything in variables to create the function so that I can just pass in the comments or the notes and it will produce the correct output.

1. ive tested this and it successfully returns a list of the positions.

   ```
   For i = 1 to 10
   n= Trim(InStr(comments,i & ".")& "</br>")
   Next
   ```
2. This is where I get lost as you will see by my incoherant nonsense:

Problem 1: I am not sure how to set the above results into a dynamic array in vbscript.

```
    a=Array(n)
```

Problem 2: I am then not sure how to use that array to allow me to subtract an array element from the next array element to create the p variable and loop it for each element in n.

```
    p=a(3)-a(2)
```

1. after I figure that out it should be a simple matter of looping the following to get the desired results:

   ```
   response.write(Mid(comments,n,p) & "</br>")
   ```

Up to this point in my programming I have been able to figure just about everything out, but this is the most complicated that I have come to yet. Again, i'm a noob programmer, so be gentle :) I appreciate any help that you geniuses can give.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you can get away with this in your ASP page but you could use a regular expression object to do some of the more complicated work.

```
strString = "New String 1.blah 2.blah 3.blah 4.blah 5.blah 6.blah"

Set objRE = New RegExp
With objRE
    .Pattern    = "\d\.\w+"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global     = True
End With

' Test method returns TRUE if a match is found
If objRE.test(strString) Then
    set match = objRE.Execute(strString)
    ' Next line will show the count of the retuned objects
    'msgbox(match.count)
    for each item in match
        MsgBox item
    next
End If

Set objRE = Nothing
```

The regex string will match a single digit followed by a period and the data that follows up until a space. If you have more the single digits you could change \d to \d+? which will grab more without being greedy.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for the Regex pointer. It was way more effective that writing 100+ lines using the 
InStr() function. This is what I came up with. It finds each occurrance of a digit followed by a period or a digit followed by a letter and then a period within a string. It then determines the number of characters between each occurrance and uses that number with the mid() function to print each occurrance and the corresponding text to a new line.

```
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.Global = True   
    objRegEx.Pattern = "\d+[.]|\d+[a-z][.]"

str = comments
Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(str)  

If colMatches.Count > 0 THEN
    For Each strMatch in colMatches 
If i="" then i=0 End if
chrNum = strMatch.FirstIndex -i
    response.write(mid(str,i,chrNum) & "</br>") 
i=strMatch.FirstIndex
Next
End If
```

As a total noob to VBScript I appreciate critisism and suggestions. If you see anything in my code that can be improved(even just housekeeping) let me know as I am 100% self taught and have no formal training. Thanks!